# c# ZFrame data extraction

Tags: c#, zeromq

I need help to understand ZFrames. Using ZeroMq with clrzmq4 binding for c#, I create a frame from a string. Then I get the string from frame and I get an empty string. Something so simple as

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ZMessage msg = new ZMessage();   
    msg.Add(new ZFrame("AABBCCDD"));            
    textBox1.Text = msg.PopString();
}
```

what do I missed?

Thanks in advance

**Edited**:
I can get the content with

```
List<ZFrame> l = msg.ToList();
byte[] by = l[0].Read();
char[] cby = new char[by.Length + 1];
for (int a = 0; a < by.Length; a++)
    cby[a] = (char)by[a];
textBox1.Text = new string(cby);
```

I cant understand why?

Comment: Did you try NetMQ? a port of zeromq to c#, might be simpler. https://github.com/zeromq/netmq

Comment: No I don't. I use ZeroMq because it looked easy and it is. Is only this problem with frames what is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is a bug in clrzmq4: https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq4/issues/110

As a workaround, if you rewind the stream in between yourself using `Position = 0`, it works, i.e.

```
var frame = new ZFrame("AABBCCDD");
frame.Position = 0;
var msg = new ZMessage {frame};
Assert.AreEqual("AABBCCDD", msg.PopString());
```